# Can't read the value member setting from the data reader to combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, valuemember

I'm setting the value member and display member from a datareader to combobox like this.

```
public void getPartyNamesCombo()
{
    SqlDataReader reader = new VotingOP().getPartyNamesToCombo();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        cmbPartyName.Items.Add(new { PartyID = reader["partyID"].ToString(), PartyName = reader["partyName"].ToString() });
    }
    cmbPartyName.ValueMember = "PartyID";
    cmbPartyName.DisplayMember = "PartyName";
}
```

I'm trying to access the id like this

```
int selectedValue = (int)cmbPartyName.SelectedValue;
MessageBox.Show("Selected value is"+selectedValue);
```

but it gives me "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'" Exception. What's wrong I'm doing here?

Comment: Even if the selected value wasn't null and you didn't get the `NullReferenceException` it still wouldn't work because your `SelectedValue` is a `string` and you're trying to cast it into an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following approach:

First: you create some class for your data items:

```
class MyDataItem 
{
    public string PartyID { get;set; }
    public string PartyName { get;set; }
}
```

Second: you use it in place of your anonymous object:

```
public void getPartyNamesCombo()
{
    SqlDataReader reader = new VotingOP().getPartyNamesToCombo();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        cmbPartyName.Items.Add(new MyDataItem() { 
            PartyID = reader["partyID"].ToString(), 
            PartyName = reader["partyName"].ToString() 
        });
    }
    cmbPartyName.ValueMember = "PartyID";
    cmbPartyName.DisplayMember = "PartyName";
}
```

Third: finally you are now able to cast your selected item to the custom data item and get its properties:

```
MyDataItem selectedItem = cmbPartyName.SelectedItem as MyDataItem;
if (selectedItem != null) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You've just selected the '{0}' party with the ID {1}",  selectedItem.PartyName, selectedItem.PartyID));
}
```

Notice here that I used the `SelecetedItem` which gives you the whole object unlike the `SelectedValue` where you only get the `PartyID`.

If you later change your mind and want to show other properties they will already be available.

Comment: yeah problem has been with the anonymous object. Now it works. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no selected value currently then the `cmbPartyName.SelectedValue` will return null. First you need to get the selected value and check if it is not null:

```
object selectedValue = cmbPartyName.SelectedValue;
if (selectedValue != null)
{
    // Now convert the selected value to integer. 
    int selectedPartyID = (int)selectedValue;

    // And now you can handle the integer.
    // ...
}
else
{
    // There is no value selected... 
}
```

Comment: Tried your code. Still items display in the combo box, though I select an item it displays no value selected. How can I solve that?

Comment: So just debug it line by line with F10 and you will see what is the problem. The solution above deals with the NullReferenceException as you asked to.